# How to convert any encoded values of special characters in a string and insert it into a JSON object in java?

Tags: java, json, special-characters, symbols

I am trying to insert a currency symbol (for example Euro) into a JSON object in java. I have the encoded string of Euro (\u20AC. We might have various other symbols, \t, and others also). When I tried with a normal string variable, it is automatically converting into the Euro symbol and tab space, but when I am inserting it into a JSON object, it is not converting. I tried using java.net.URLDecoder.decode() method, but it is also not working.

```
    String s1 = "pqr\u20ACab\tcd";

    JSONObject temp = new JSONObject();
    temp.put("field", java.net.URLDecoder.decode(s1));
    System.out.println(s1);
    System.out.println(temp);
```

Below is the output I got

```
   pqr€ab   cd
   {"field":"pqr\u20ACab\tcd"}
```

Comment: You don't use URLDecoder. Just put the string in the JSON directly. What's the concrete problem?

Comment: @JBNizet I tried putting the string directly. Even then I got the same output. The problem is I want 'pqr€ab   cd' in JSON output as well which is not happening. Is there any way to get the above string as output in JSON also?

Comment: You can't have that output in JSON, as that would be invalid JSON. In a JSON string, a tab must be encoded as `\t`. What you seem to be missing is that if you get the string out of your JSON object and print it, you will get the original string.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of your exact requirement but for solving the above case.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "utf-8");
temp.write(writer);
writer.flush();
String jsonString = new String(out.toByteArray(),"utf-8");
JSONObject newJSON = new JSONObject(jsonString);
String newJsonString = newJSON.getString("field");
System.out.println(newJsonString );
```

Answer (score 0):

com.google.gson.JsonParser unescapes the euro sign:

```
    String s1 = "pqr\u20ACab\tcd";
    JSONObject temp = new JSONObject();
    temp.put("field", s1);
    System.out.println(JsonParser.parseString(String.valueOf(temp)));
```

This print {"field":"pqr€ab\tcd"}